# How does lldb handle special purpose _swift_runtime_on_report function?

Tags: swift, lldb

While analysing how Swift `assertionFailure()` works under the hood I noticed the actual fatal error is reported through `_swift_runtime_on_report` function. Its implementation is defined here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/runtime/Errors.cpp as

```
SWIFT_NOINLINE SWIFT_RUNTIME_EXPORT void
_swift_runtime_on_report(uintptr_t flags, const char *message,
                         RuntimeErrorDetails *details) {
  // Do nothing. This function is meant to be used by the debugger.

  // The following is necessary to avoid calls from being optimized out.
  asm volatile("" // Do nothing.
               : // Output list, empty.
               : "r" (flags), "r" (message), "r" (details) // Input list.
               : // Clobber list, empty.
               );
}
```

Clearly it's just a fancy write up for a function that literally does nothing. It's just sitting there waiting for `lldb` to be treated *specially*. What I mean by this is:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x7fff64d1cd50 <+0>: push   rbp
    0x7fff64d1cd51 <+1>: mov    rbp, rsp
    0x7fff64d1cd54 <+4>: pop    rbp
    0x7fff64d1cd55 <+5>: ret    
    0x7fff64d1cd56 <+6>: nop    word ptr cs:[rax + rax]
```

The x86-64 isn't really that relevant here. The fact the first line (with the arrow ->) fatal errors (whatever that exactly means) in Xcode is. Interestingly even setting a breakpoint at memory address `0x7fff64d1cd50` beforehand won't trigger it, it will fatal error anyway without hitting the breakpoint.

When I tinker with the program counter (rip) I can skip to `0x7fff64d1cd51` and catch breakpoint at `0x7fff64d1cd54` without triggering the fatal error. So it seems plausible reading program memory at `0x7fff64d1cd50` is caught by `lldb` which eventually fatal errors in a graceful way.

And now comes the most confusing part of the riddle. In my minimalistic XCode project I have `main.swift` consisting of

```
assertionFailure()
```

But if I add intentionally a C function defined like this (body being irrelevant here):

```
#include <stdint.h>
_swift_runtime_on_report(uintptr_t flags, const char *message,
                         void *details) {
    int i = 0;
    i++;
    return i;
}
```

it will confuse `lldb` enough to lift the memory restriction on vanilla `_swift_runtime_on_report` function (at this point I can now catch breakpoints at `0x7fff64d1cd50`). Eventually it omits the "graceful" fatal error step and it will fail on `ud2` (i.e. x86 deliberate bad instruction)

Interestingly it's perfectly legal to call my local "imposter" function from Swift too, everything works like it's a perfectly normal C function.

So my question is how `lldb` is exactly failing in `_swift_runtime_on_report` / `0x7fff64d1cd50` ? And why I was able to break this mechanism with this local C function that isn't even called. Obviously through symbol / definition clash, but what is really happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

_swift_runtime_on_report is a function that exists so that lldb can set a breakpoint on it, and retrieve some info about the error to show the user.  You can see that breakpoint while debugging a swift program by issuing the command:

```
(lldb) break list -i
Current breakpoints:
Kind: shared-library-event
-1: address = dyld[0x00000000000121ad], locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count = 1

  -1.1: where = dyld`_dyld_debugger_notification, address = 0x00000001000221ad, resolved, hit count = 1 

Kind: swift-language-runtime-report
-2: address = libswiftCore.dylib[0x00007fff66b14380], locations = 1, resolved = 1, hit count = 1

  -2.1: where = libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report, address = 0x00007fff689d5380, resolved, hit count = 1
```

Swift promises to call this function whenever it's come across a fatal error, before it tears down your program. That allows lldb - in normal debugging - to catch the error and report it to you rather than having the program exit out from under you.  It also allows the swift REPL to catch and clean up from any throws that might happen at the top-level of the REPL, since they would otherwise cause the REPL to exit.

When I build and debug the swift file with the one line "assertionFailure()", the debugger stops with:

```
Fatal error: file errors/errors.swift, line 2
2020-09-29 16:52:40.373185-0700 errors[17428:2120547] Fatal error: file errors/errors.swift, line 2
Process 17428 stopped
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = Fatal error
    frame #0: 0x00007fff689d5380 libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report
libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x7fff689d5380 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x7fff689d5381 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x7fff689d5384 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x7fff689d5385 <+5>: retq   
Target 0: (errors) stopped.
```

The only slightly tricky thing here is that if you put a breakpoint on this function as well, lldb will just report the error in the stop reason, since that's a higher priority stop reason.  Another thing that might be confusing you is that lldb never shows the breakpoints it has inserted, it always shows the instruction that it overwrote.  If you aren't seeing the breakpoints you inserted, that's as designed.

Anyway, I couldn't tell which part of this wasn't working for you?  Is the breakpoint not getting set?  Or is it not getting hit?  Or did you have another question I'm just missing?

Comment: That explains a lot. And my "regular" bp in `_swift_runtime_on_report` wasn't getting hit but I could still set it. Even more interestingly when the aforementioned "imposter" C function is defined in my program the lldb "special" bp no longer appears in `break list -i`. I assume lldb finds the `_swift_runtime_on_report` symbol but since it's not in `libswiftCore.dylib` it ignores it. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: lldb seems a little inconsistent about whether it reports the runtime error stop reason or the breakpoint at the same function.  It looks like we report the user breakpoint if it has any locations apart from the one in libSwiftCore.dylib, but if there's only one location we report the error stop.  That seems a little odd though this is a pretty corner-y corner case.  But I was never able to get lldb not to set the internal one.

Comment: But I don’t even need any bp in the „imposter” C function, it’s sheer existence in the program is enough to affect the output of break list -i

Comment: That seems like a bug, but sadly one that I can't reproduce.  If you have a little project and some steps that show this behavior, please file it with the Swift bug-reporter (http://bugs.swift.com)